# Suppress output of scan function in R ('Read X items')

Tags: r

I am creating an R notebook using RStudio. Calling the `scan` function on a large number of files creates an equally large number of messages of the form `Read X items`, all of which appear in the notebook on their own separate lines. Argh! Wrapping the call in `suppressMessages`, `capture.output`, `invisible`, or `suppressWarnings` makes no difference.

How can I keep those `Read X items` messages out of the notebook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the [`quiet = TRUE` argument](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/scan.html).